# Functions on discrete sets are continuous, but isn't $\mathbb{N}$ a discrete set? How can a function defined on $\mathbb{N}$ be continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm reviewing my old calculus notes. Here is a well known theorem (I think also used as definition in later analysis classes):

> $f: A \to B$ is continuous $\iff$ the pre-image of any open set $C \subset f(A)$ is open as well

Using this theorem it is easy to see that functions on discrete sets are continuous. However, it makes no sense that a function on $\mathbb{N}$ is continuous. My issue is, can't we take a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ as a discrete set? I think there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Why do you think that make no sense that a funcion on $\Bbb N$ is continuous?

Comment: How can a function on $\mathbb N$ be *dis*continuous?

Comment: You guys win, I only used intuition. I just pictured a graph of a function defined on $\mathbb{N}$, and didn't bother checking with standard epsilon delta definition.

Comment: I don't understand the first title sentence. Yes, $\Bbb N$ is discrete.

Comment: every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is open, since the point sets are open, i.e., $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete. you have just told us that every function defined on a discrete space is continuous.

Comment: @CSquared what is a formal definition for a discrete set (I guess a definition from topology)? I get that all discrete sets are both open and closed, but not when is something discrete (other than intuition).

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes a discrete space is a set space equipped with the discrete topology. every subset of a set equipped with the discrete topology is open. the naturals (when viewed as either a subspace of the reals or just a set endowed with the discrete topology, both are equivalent) is a discrete space

Comment: Intuitively, continuity of a function $f$ means that a sufficiently small change in the input $x$ produces only a small change in the output $f(x)$. If the space of inputs is discrete, then a "sufficiently small" change there means no change at all, so of course the change of output will also be small (because it's also no change at all). So $f$ automatically satisfies the intuitive requirement for continuity.

Comment: To reprhase Andreas Blass's comment to hopefully make it even more intuitively obvious: $f$ is continuous at a point $a$, if for every point $x$ near $a, f(x)$ will be near $f(a)$. But in a discrete set, "near $a$" means" $= a$", so the condition of continuity becomes: if $x = a$, then $f(x)$ is near $f(a)$. As $f(a)$ is always near to itself, all functions on a discrete space are continuous, no matter the topology of their codomain.